# Prevent duplicate schedule job on Azure App service when scale out

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a Nuxt app deployed on Azure App Service, with `cron` library to run schedule jobs. However I found that If there are more than one instance running, the schedule job will be duplicated. What is the proper way to handle it? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using azure webjob with timer trigger?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one instance of your app running, then you have more than one instance of cron running (I'm assuming you are referring to the npm module in your case). Both are going to activate on the same schedule since it's coded into both apps. And of course if you scale beyond that, you would have three, four, five jobs running.

There are a few options that let you run singleton jobs on a timer such as adding a WebJob to your App Service, creating a Logic App, and running an Azure Function. For a basic JS script I would [recommend the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=javascript#packages---functions-2x-and-higher). You create a JSON file that defines the schedule you want to run it on (just like cron), it's JS so you can probably just copy your code over along with other npm modules you need, and you can set Configuration just like web apps so if your job needs to connect to storage or a database you can have connection strings and other info there just like you do for your existing web app.

Comment: Hi mherzig, I have an idea that to expose a web service call like '/api/TriggerScheduleJob', and let a script to periodically trigger the call, as load balancer will route the job to either one instance. Is it a terrible idea? Anyway thanks for your help. I will take a look to Azure Function.

Comment: That could work as well. I suppose you could have a Logic App that runs on a timer that just makes that HTTP call, and yes it would only be routed to one of the instances.